# symfony entity createAt and updateAt type is datetime, when i wrote api,the result is bad

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am sorry for the title being so non-descriptive but the question I am asking is way to broad to fit in 10 words.
when i use symfony entity createAt and updateAt type is datetime, when i wrote api,the result is bad.I not want change createAt and updateAt to string type.thanks
entity defiend is like this:

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updateAt", type="datetime", options={"comment":"更新时间"})
     */
    private $updateAt;
```

the method in repository :

```
public function getList($userId, $isMime)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.title,c.nodeName as node_name, c.node, c.updateAt as datetime');
        if($isMime == 0){
            $qb->leftJoin(ApprovalInformation::class,'a','WITH','a.flowId = 11 and a.itemId = c.id');
            $qb->where('a.approverId = :uid');
        }else{
            $qb->where('c.userId = :uid');
        }
        $qb->setParameter('uid', $userId);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

controller

```
$list = $cardRepo->getList($this->user->getId(), $mime);
        return $this->json([
            'code' => 1,
            'msg' => '获取成功',
            'data' => $list
        ]);
{
    "code": 1,
    "msg": "获取成功",
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "测试报告",
            "node_name": "处长批示",
            "node": 11,
            "datetime": {
                "date": "2019-05-07 19:04:00.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "测试报告2222",
            "node_name": "处长审批",
            "node": 2,
            "datetime": {
                "date": "2019-05-07 19:28:14.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai"
            }
        }
    ]
}
my except result like is:

{
    "code": 1,
    "msg": "获取成功",
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "测试报告",
            "node_name": "处长批示",
            "node": 11,
            "datetime": "2019-05-07 19:04:00",
        },
        {
            "title": "测试报告2222",
            "node_name": "处长审批",
            "node": 2,
            "datetime": "2019-05-07 19:28:14",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know an efficient solution.thanks

Comment: implement https://php.net/jsonserializable for your card entity. in there, don't let datetime encode itself, but instead call `$updateAt->format(...)`

Comment: how does your $this->json() function look like? you'll have to make sure your DateTime is serialized in the way you want to expose it.

Comment: `$this->json()` is the default symfony `ControllerTrait`,  `JsonResponse`-generating helper function, that essentially just calls `json_encode` and puts it verbatim in a response object (setting content-type headers and stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$this->json()` in your controller which will serialize your entity using `json_encode()`. This is what is causing the datetime to be returned like this:

```sh
$ php -a

php > echo json_encode(new DateTime());
{"date":"2019-05-07 14:20:22.137677","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}
```

There is multiple ways around this. You can create an array from your data before calling `$this->json()`:

```php
return $this->json(
    array_map(
        function ($entity) {
            return [
                'title' => $entity->getTitle(),
                ...
                'updateAt' => $entity->getUpdateAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ];
        },
        $list
    )
);
```

Alternatively you could use the Symfony Serializer: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#serializing-an-object

If you use the Serializer, make sure you also have the DateTimeNormalizer registered.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it following code in your getUpadateAt function in entity:

```
return $this->updateAt->format('Y-m-d  h:I:s);
```

Comment: this is not really what causes the problem, since `getUpdateAt` is *not* called by `json_encode` (which `$this->json` uses). but as a side effect you return an unexpected value from `getUpdateAt`(I would expect a datetime, when it's defined as a datetime)

Comment: @Techie Adict thanks, I test it but is not a string